# Magento 2 : How to add configurable product to cart with the selected custom options?

Tags: magento2.2, cart, configurable-product

I had a configurable product with two variants such as color and size and I have one customizable custom option, I am trying to add this product to cart with a custom controller, but it says the required options are missing.